# How set my custom name to foreing key in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

How i can set foreign key name in my entity jpa.
This is a example of name generated `FK3jrphg3ll698ta68xi074uesj`.
This not name friendly, i want can set the name friendly for her.

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="est_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    private State state;
```

The @ForeignKey from hibernate annotations is deprecated and from javax.persistence not have this option(i not found)

I am Using `spring-boot version 2.0.0.RELEASE`

Comment: You didn't find this option? How did you search? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#foreignKey--

Comment: i see this too, but the attribute name not exists em @foreignKey
for me only show `value` and `foreignKeyDefinition`.
I do not understand the down vote in question, i citted in question this note.

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "est_id"))
```

This is clearly shown in the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html)

Comment: the attribute name not exists in my version
I using spring, like citted above

Comment: i see this docs too, but the attribute `name` not exists em @foreignKey for me,  only have `value` and `foreignKeyDefinition`.